# My code won’t delete lines of unnecessary data under the data I’m trying to keep

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub DeleteExtraValues ()

    Dim I as Integer, strValueToFind As String, lngRows As           Long, she As Worksheet
     Set an = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
     LngRows = sh.Range(“A1048576”).End(xlUp).Row
     strValueToFind = “DCAP”
     For I = 1 To lngRows
        If InStr(Cells(I,1).Value, strValueToFind) = 0 Then
           If Cells(I,1).Value = “” Then
           Else
               Rows(I).Delete
                I = I-1
           End If
      End If
    Next I
End Sub
```

When running this, it will delete the cells above the data I want to keep and then will stop once it gets to the first cell that contains “DCAP”. I need it also to delete any unnecessary information after the last cell that contains “DCAP”.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your problem - you want to keep all the rows above the single row that contains "DCAP" in column A, and delete all the rows under that row?

Comment: I’m trying to delete all the rows that don’t contain “DCAP”. On a week to week basis, the data will change and the report will pull some data that doesn’t contain “DCAP” and is unnecessary.

Comment: When deleting rows, you need to start at the bottom and work up. If not, when you delete a row, the counter will get confused and you will have unexpected results.  Or just use the AutoFilter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.  It removes every row that doesn't contain DCAP in the first column.

```
Dim r As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

r = 1
LastRow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

Do Until r > LastRow
   DoEvents
   If InStr(1, Cells(r, 1), "DCAP") > 0 Then
        r = r + 1
   Else 
        Cells(r, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        LastRow = LastRow - 1
   End If

Loop

MsgBox
```

"done"

Comment: Where do you add a line or code so that it won’t delete the header line? Row1?

Comment: @Djhans26...change r = 1 to whatever row you want it to start looking at the data

Comment: How do I enter a vlookup function in column d in ws1 and compare it to ws2, column C, where the cells contain the the common “DCAP”? The data will change week to week so I need the function to perform only on rows that have values in column A.

Comment: Sorry from workbook 1 to workbook 2, not ws1 to ws2.

Comment: @Djhans26.....I'm not sure what you are trying to do.  The original question was how to delete rows in a workbook with "DCAP" in a specific column.  There was nothing about a 2nd workbook.  How are the 2 workbooks related?

Comment: Sorry, that was the first part of my problem but now my second problem is that I need to do a vlookup from the data from the first code to another workbook. That has possible matching data that I need to delete.

Comment: My formula is currently:                                                                           Range(“D2”).select

Comment: @Djhans26....do you need a vlookup?  Can't you just run the code in both workbooks to remove the "DCAP" lines?

Comment: I need a vlookup as I will then delete the lines that match and add the rows that don’t match to the ygl dcs workbook.

Comment: @Djhans26.....alright..........that makes more sense now.  I personally would do all of that with VBA and stay away from vLookUps

Comment: That’s what I thought as well but what I have wrote so far isn’t working.

Comment: @Djhans26....what part isn't working?  I tend to write things in smaller pieces...Once the first piece works like I want it to, then I move on to the next piece.....this makes it easier to troubleshoot (at least for me)

Comment: How do you change this code from looking for text to looking for value ranging from -10000 to 10000?

Comment: @Djhans26...Try something like this:  If val(Cells(r, 1)) < 10000 and val(cells(r,1)) > -10001Then.....

Comment: When I replace this with the “Instr” line, it doesn’t delete the rows below the data so there are still rows that have text. How do I fix this?

Comment: @Djhans26...........The code I showed above was to delete 1 row at a time.  The latest example was to replace the "instr" with the "val".  It will still only delete 1 row at a time

Comment: I replaced the “instr” with the “Val” and it works, deleting rows with text with the data above the necessary data to keep but it will stop and won’t delete the rows under the data to keep with text in the cells. Is there a way to do the full sheet?

Comment: @Djhans26.....The original code I suggested had a "Do Loop" that would go until the end of the data. It would check each row and should delete it if it meets the criteria in the "if" statement

Comment: When I replace the instr with Val it gives me an error stating “Cells(r,4)=<Application-defined or object-defined error>”. How do I fix this?

Comment: If cells(s,4).value>0 or Cells(s,4).Value < 0 then

Comment: I have fixed the line, the problem now is that the loop stops and won’t delete all the lines that don’t contain a value

Comment: @Djhans26.........Have you stepped through the code to see what line it is stopping on?  How many rows does it still need to look at?  A few, most of them, etc.?  The code I suggested finds the last row and then subtracts 1 each time a row is deleted.  This in theory, should move through all of the rows.  Are you adding any rows during your process?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'depending on your data you may have to change to a specific range using last row and column

' change the `Field` to the column that contains "DCAP"   
    With rng 
        .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="<>DCAP", Operator:=xlAnd 'select all cells that are not "DCAP"
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete 'don't delete the header row
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
```